# Linked list - access violation... Where?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to implement a linked list in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct el{
    int number;
    struct el *next;
} linkedlist;

linkedlist* newel(){
    linkedlist *newelement = (linkedlist*)malloc(sizeof(linkedlist));
    newelement->number = 10;
    newelement->next=NULL;
    return newelement;
}

void add(linkedlist **head, linkedlist *item){
    if(!*head){
        *head = item;
    }
    else{
        item->next = *head;
        *head = item;
    }
}

void prnt(linkedlist *head){
    while(head!=NULL){
        printf("%d\n", head->number);
        head=head->next;
    }
}

int main(){

    linkedlist *hd;
    add(&hd,newel());
    add(&hd,newel());
    add(&hd,newel());
    prnt(hd);

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

and I get:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x010c14e9 in test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcccccccc.
```

I tried to debug and the problem is in prnt function. It seems it doesn't see NULL when head points to the last element... it's just going ahead.
I have no idea how to fix it for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your main function, initialize:

```
linkedlist *hd = NULL;
```

Answer (score 2):

`linkedlist *hd;` This may lead to error. Because initially it may have some `garbage` value. so you have to NULL to head `linkedlist *hd = NULL;`

Answer (score 1):

I think the cause of exception is that `hd` is an uninitialized variable. In your environment, it seem to be carrying the value `0xcccccccc`. The check `if(!*head)` probably never evaluated to be`` `true ``.